# html quotations mix up with php

Tags: php, javascript, html, if-statement

I got some html code

```
<?php 
    if($loggedIn){
       echo "<div id='navigation'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='javascript:toggleLayer('video');'>Global</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='javascript:toggleLayer('info');'>About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='javascript:toggleLayer('register_main');'>Join!</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>"};
```

But when I click on the url's on the website, they happen not to execute the javascript code.
after inspectiong one of the elements I found out that

```
<a video');'="" href="javascript:toggleLayer(">Global</a>
```

is the code generated, which is wrong ofcourse.

My only clue would be that it should be

```
     <a href="javascript:toggleLayer('video');">Global</a>
```

Though i have no clue how to fix that inside the echo, because it has to be in between the if-statement

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need a semi-colon after the </div>" just before the closing brace

Comment: Also you need to replace all `='` with `=\"` and `'>` with `\">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
<?php if($loggedIn){
   echo "<div id='navigation'>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href='javascript:toggleLayer('video');'>Global</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='javascript:toggleLayer('info');'>About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='javascript:toggleLayer('register_main');'>Join!</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>"}; ?>
```

with:

```
<?php if($loggedIn){ ?>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:toggleLayer('video');">Global</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:toggleLayer('info');">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:toggleLayer('register_main');">Join!</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

When using quotes inside of strings `" I said "Hello" "`. You need to escape the matching surrounding quotes like: `" I said \"Hello\" "`.

Comment: I didnt know it was possible to just stopphp like ?> and continue at a point later in time

Comment: @Quitta Absolutely. I think it might be faster than echo too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
...
<a href='javascript:toggleLayer(\"video\");'>Global</a>
...
```

Comment: There's no need to escape double-quotes if they're only inside single quotes.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt thought about escaping them :)

Comment: @arxanas, without the escpaing, the echo generates troubles :p

Answer (score 0):

The problem are your quotation marks.
You have to escape the ones inside the `<a>` tags where you set the params for your javascript function e.g. 'video'